# what is object id in clearcase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have a very basic question in clearcase.

does every version of an file have same OID? As far as I know each version is an object and each object will have a different OID. 
I even checked with cleartool dump and each version has different OID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precisely, as explained in "[How to find oid and uuid of an element in IBM Rational ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21407966)"

> Every single object in a ClearCase VOB is referenced by its oid ("object ID").
>   The oid is unique inside the VOB.
>   **This does not apply only to file, but to all objects in the VOB.**
>
> - Element
> - Version
> - Metadata
>
> ClearCase uses the oid internally. The oid is invisible for common user's operation. However, in some error messages, you see a reference to an oid.

To find the oid from an object, you use :

```
cleartool dump <object>
```

To find the object from an oid, you use :

```
cleartool dump oid:<object>
```

For theses commands to work, you need to be in a view and in the corresponding VOB. This is necessary in order to generate the path/file name.

`<object>` can be anything defined as an object for ClearCase. Like for instance:

- element `<file>@@`
- version `<file>` or `<file>@@\main\......`
- type `lbtype:<name>`
- VOB or replica object `vob:<vobtag>`

You can also run "`cleartool describe -long oid:<oid>`" on the oid while set in a view to the root of the VOB to which the element resides, and the output will return an element name.
See "[Identifying elements by the source container path](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21234502)"

Comment: Generally, the Object ID is even unique across VOBs. It is based on a microsecond-resolution timestamp and the creating host's primary MAC address. It's enforced within the VOB, but not across VOBs. OIDs are also preserved in relocated objects. This means that you CAN have duplicate OID's, but it's pretty rare. (In 17 years of working with ClearCase, I've seen it ONCE: caused by a relocate -update where using both the source and destination of the relocate during a build caused some really odd clearmake errors.)

Comment: so oid for each version for the same file will be different isnt it?

Comment: @user2636464 yes it will

Comment: @BrianCowan I have found a 2012 thread where you mentioned that OID composition (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014845091), but I haven't found any more link. Is there any documentation on that?

Comment: No there really isn't, mostly because it can change. Generation had to change once when systems started being fast enough and parallel enough to generate 2 objects within the same microsecond.